# Xcode Utilities rigth panel don't lord information anymore while in Storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode7

I have a weird problem, and can't figure it out.

The comme from the storyboard in XCode Version 7.0 (7A220).

When I display my main.storyboard clicking on the file, everything appear, but if I select UI elements or ViewControllers nothing get displayed in the Utilities rigth panel tabs. It used to work fine a hour ago.

Here are the screenshots:

This is the Main.storyboard opened in Xcode, and I selected a random UIView.(It does the same with any kind of elements)

[image]

Now, as you can see, nothing is displayed here. Usually I can access the element properties...

[image]
[image]

This one is the only one who still appear, but it loads weirdly and takes time.

[image]

I don't have another computer for testing, and I can't work without this, so if you have any idea!

Comment: this is just a tmp xcode bug by my opinion. happend to me before, came bug after a computer restart.

Comment: Happened to me as well. An Xcode restart seems to fix the issue.

Comment: Well I restarted XCode and computer many times without success. I will be able to try again next monday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting computer or Xcode never solves the problem.

I did two things, don't know which solved the problem.

First thing was to go into Window > project > 'yourProjectname' and the press the "delete derived data" option.

Second thing was to close the concerned tab on Xcode.

Hope this can help